# Write GitLab CI variables to file

Tags: php, continuous-integration, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

How could I write GitLab CI variables to config file like this:

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - touch "config.json"
    - echo "{"database":"$DB_NAME"}" >> config.json
```

The variables couldn't be resolved. Always I get the following json in file `config.json`: `{"database":"$DB_NAME"}` but I want this `{"database":"my_database_name"}`

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: FWIW, ain't your double quotes on the `echo` matched incorrectly? The spec says that `In double quoted strings if you need to include a literal double quote in your string you can escape it by prefixing it with a backslash \`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problem via shell script with parameters like this:

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - bash setup_config_for_tests.sh $DB_NAME $DB_PASSWORD $SALT $HOST_PROD $USERNAME_PROD $PASSWORD_PROD
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# create config file
touch "config.json"

# write config json to config file
echo "{\"param1\": \"${1}\"}" >> config.json
```