# How read predefined variables from gitlab CI/CD with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, gitlab, gitlab-ci, spring-boot-actuator

I need to read some CI/CD variables like `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH, CI_PIPELINE_ID` through Spring Boot API.
Currently, I'm using Actuator also. Is there a stright way to read these variables from the environment? I'm using Gitlab and Gradle.

I have tried `git-commit-id-plugin`. can I trust this plugin in a production environment?
Example - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-git-information

or Do I need to write those files into a file and read them after.
Example - [Write GitLab CI variables to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62904062/write-gitlab-ci-variables-to-file)

Comment: If I remember correctly, you should be able to use ${VARIABLE_NAME} in the springboot application.properties file. Ex: ${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}.

Comment: thank you @Soulfly. I'll look into that. I have found that git information can be exposed using the same actuator endpoint by adding  management.info.git.mode=full to application properties.